# Visual Studio Text Visualizer missing text

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I am debugging a string variable in Visual Studio using the Text Visualizer. However, it seems that **a large part in the middle of the string** is missing. What is the reason behind this?

[image]

Comment: Long text was displayed correctly with VS 2015 until Update 1 was installed.  The Text Visualizer now does as is explained in the answer below and so fat Microsoft has not said they changed it or why.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Text Visualizer in Visual Studio can only display about 32,700 characters. If your string is longer than that, **it will automatically replaces the excess part in the middle of the string with `...`.**

I found this out the hard way.

**Edit**: this seems to have been fixed in Update 2. If you're on Update 1, see Diamond's answer.

Comment: Nasty thing, they don't even notify that the text is being trimmed. Spent hours before found that out. Any news on this? Is this confirmed to be a bug?

Comment: One would think they'd truncate the END of the string instead of the middle... would have made it a little more obvious that it was VS and not my web service call causing the problem...

Comment: So thankful you for this info ... I killed almost whole day because of this issue ... Visual Studio truncated XML document and i saw just 1 node, meanwhile code says that there are 2 nodes ... It was very frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

This is an issue that was introduced with Visual Studio 2015 Update 1 as reported here: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2016177/text-visualizer-misses-corrupts-text-in-long-strings.

Microsoft will have a permanent fix for this in the first update after Update 1. In the meantime, use the following workaround: You can set the length at which the Text Visualizer will truncate by adding a registry key. Use the following command to set the length to a larger number (example 250000):

`reg add HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Debugger /v TextVisualizerStringLimit /t REG_DWORD /d [number]`

Alternatively use a previous version of Visual Studio if you have one installed.

Comment: Not sure when their next update is, but as of 14.0.24720.00 Update 1, this bug still exists.

Comment: There is a Release Candidate for Update 2 available from here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx. It may contain a fix for the issue. Just depends on what else it breaks ...

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164759.aspx).

1. Create new project **Class Library**
2. Add new Form **MessageForm** with **TextBox** inside, check **MaxLength** and **Multiline** properties of **TextBox**.
3. Add .cs file with folowing content:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers;
using System.Windows.Forms;    
[assembly: System.Diagnostics.DebuggerVisualizer(
typeof(TextVisualizer.DebuggerSide),
typeof(VisualizerObjectSource),
Target = typeof(String),
Description = "My Visualizer")]
namespace TextVisualizer
{
    public class DebuggerSide : DialogDebuggerVisualizer
    {
        protected override void Show(IDialogVisualizerService windowService, IVisualizerObjectProvider objectProvider)
        {
            var message = new MessageForm();
            ((TextBox) message.Controls.Find("textbox1",false)[0]).Text = objectProvider.GetObject().ToString();
            message.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

4. Build Project
5. Locate the DLL that contains the visualizer you have built and
   copy the DLL to either of the following locations:

   - VisualStudioInstallPath\Common7\Packages\Debugger\Visualizers
   - My Documents\VisualStudioVersion\Visualizers

If you want to use a managed visualizer for remote debugging, copy the DLL to the same path on the remote computer.
Restart the debugging session. For more information, see [How to: Install a Visualizer.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sb2yca43.aspx)